# vscodeが勝手に英語化され、日本語に戻そうとしたらエラー

Tags: vscode

勝手に英語化されたvscodeの日本語化ができず困っています。

vscodeが突然英語化され、調べた限りアップデートされると英語化されるようです。
そこでcommand+shift+p→configure display languageによって日本語に戻そうとしたら、

```
connect ENOENT /Users/自分の名前/Library/Application Support/Code/1.38.1-shared.sock
```

というエラーが発生しました。「connect ENOENT　1.38.1-shared.sock　エラー」などでググりましたが、具体的な解決策がわからなかったのでこちらでアドバイスいただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

以下、補足

拡張機能から日本語化しようとしましたが、それもダメでした。

[image: 拡張機能から日本語化を試みるも失敗してエラー]

Comment: OSは何ですか？いったんアンインストールし、フォルダーも削除して、インストールし直しで直りませんか？

Comment: ちなみに、完全なアンインストール方法はこちら。[VS Codeをアンインストールするには](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1810/12/news026.html)

Comment: macOS High Sierraです。リロードしてもダメだったので、アンインストールしてみます。ありがとうございました。